# how can replace multiple chars of string in jquery

Tags: jquery, string, replace, char

```
var stringVal = "../folder1/folder2/image1.jpg";   
stringVal = stringVal.replace(/[../]/g , "");
```

It will replace all `/` of string, but I want just replace `../`.

How can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex **[`\.{2}\/`](https://regex101.com/r/tS9zO3/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

> `[../]` is a `character class` that means `any character from . or /`

```js
var stringVal = "../folder1/folder2/image1.jpg";
stringVal = stringVal.replace(/\.{2}\//g, "");

document.write(stringVal);
```

Comment: You're regex has an extra `]` and `/`. BTW, `\.\.` is shorter than `\.{2}`.

Comment: thank you Pranav C Balan, I accept your answer, @vijayP thank you too

Comment: @MojtabaSh : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Can you use following:

```
"../folder1/folder2/image1.jpg".replace("../","")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way if you don't want to get into the regex stuff.

```html
stringVal.split("../").join("")
```

otherwise you'll need to escape the control characters in your regular expression. Here's another answer that should help:
[Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)